# How to remove adjacent duplicate case sensitive characters from a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

How can I remove adjacent duplicate characters in a string without considering case?

For example:

```
string = 'HaPpy Bbirthday!!!'
```

Expected Output:

```
'Hay irthday'
```

**Note**: Only adjacent duplicate characters have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with key `str.lower`:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

x = 'HaPpy Bbirthday!!!'

grouper = map(list, map(itemgetter(1), groupby(x, key=str.lower)))
res = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(i for i in grouper if len(i) == 1))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to solve this without using any inbuilt functions?

Comment: @Santosh, Probably, but that's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thanks a lot jpp for the solution.. See if you can solve it without using inbuilt functions.